# Set TextLabel's text in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am coming to you for a little issue I have, that might actually not be that complicated but that i have struggled about for now about an hour...

I defined a TableViewCell in a TableViewController. This TableViewCell has three UIImage and two textLabels. I implemented the following methods :

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}
```

(which in my sense defines the number of rows)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendListCell")   
    cellOutlet.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

On this second method, the "cellOutlet" is an instance of the class that defines my cell, in which I modify one of the textLabel's text.
"fruits" is a simple array of Strings that are supposed to be displayed in every cell of my app one by one.

Compilation goes fine, but when accessing the page in question, the app crashes saying

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My question is the following :

Would you have any idea of what is done wrong in term of accessing my textLabel's text ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try `cell.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]` and also check your outlet is properly connected or not

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a custom TableViewCell class you have to

- Set the class of the cell in Interface Builder to the custom class
- Cast the cell accordingly in `cellForRow...` (assuming the name is `MyTableViewCell`)

  ```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendListCell" for:indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendListCell")   
    cell.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

and also check "cell" should not be nil at the time of calling  `cell.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

Even if your custom UITableViewCell class (e.g. FruitsCell) has some labels, the standard UITableViewCell doesn't (apart from one, which is its 'label' property). In your code, the 'cell' property is of type UITableViewCell, which has no cellOutlet or nameTextLabel property to access.

If you set up your custom cell in IB, be sure to connect all your labels from IB with the code in your Swift-File, e.g. FruitsCell.swift, that contains the FruitsCell class.

Then cast the 'cell' in your ViewControllers delegate method as e.g. FruitCell instead of UITableViewCell. Only then you can access the labels of that class that you set up in IB.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // casting to your Class
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendListCell") as! FruitCell   

    // accessing that Class' properties
    cell.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]

    // returning cell of type FruitCell
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Hey There ! Thanks for your answer and happy new year ! 
So I just casted the cell, same way you did, which allowed me to access the nameTextLabel. 
The only difference in my code with what you wrote is `    cell.nameTextLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]` instead of `    cell.nameTextLabel.text = fruits[indexPath.row]` Xcode insists on unwrapping the textLabel and that results in having an empty cell... Maybe you'd have an idea about what's exactly wrong about it ? The data i try to store into the Label is valid and can be printed so i assume it's really only about the Label itself